# unmet dependencies: initramfs-tools [Xubuntu 12.04]

Tags: 12.04, apt, update-manager, dependencies

How would one resolve this unmet dependencies issue I've encountered ?

When running the following cmd:

```
root@ubuntu1204-cshr3:~# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (< 0.99ubuntu13.1.1~) but 0.99ubuntu13.4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

root@ubuntu1204-cshr3:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
initramfs-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
initramfs-tools
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 115 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-bin (<< 0.99ubuntu13.1.1~); however:
Version of initramfs-tools-bin on system is 0.99ubuntu13.4.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apparmor:
apparmor depends on initramfs-tools; however:
Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apparmor (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

udev depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.92bubuntu63); however:
Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing udev (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

network-manager depends on udev; however:
Package udev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing network-manager (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
initramfs-tools
apparmor
udev
network-manager
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

additional system details:

```
root@ubuntu1204-cshr3:~# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu1204--cshr3-root 18G 2.7G 14G 16% /
udev 367M 12K 367M 1% /dev
tmpfs 150M 312K 150M 1% /run
none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
none 375M 84K 375M 1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1 228M 70M 146M 33% /boot

root@ubuntu1204-cshr3:~# uname -r
3.2.0-40-generic

root@ubuntu1204-cshr3:~# apt-get update 
[source.list output edited due to <10 reputation]
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise Release_gpg
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates Release_gpg                   
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports Release_gpg                 
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise Release                               
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates Release                       
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports Release                     
Hit h-t-t-p //ppa_launchpad_net precise Release_gpg                               
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/main Sources                          
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/restricted Sources                    
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/universe Sources                      
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/multiverse Sources                    
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/main i386 Packages                    
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/universe i386 Packages                
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security Release_gpg                    
Hit h-t-t-p //extras_ubuntu_com precise Release_gpg                               
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/main Sources
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/restricted Sources
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/universe Sources              
Hit h-t-t-p //ppa_launchpad_net precise Release                                   
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/multiverse Sources            
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/main i386 Packages            
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages        
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit h-t-t-p //extras_ubuntu_com precise Release                                   
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security Release              
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/main Sources       
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/restricted Sources          
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/universe Sources            
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/multiverse Sources          
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/main i386 Packages          
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit h-t-t-p //ppa_launchpad_net precise/main Sources                              
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //extras_ubuntu_com precise/main Sources                              
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex   
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/main Translation-en         
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/restricted Translation-en   
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise/universe Translation-en               
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/main Translation-en           
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en     
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-updates/universe Translation-en       
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/main Sources                   
Hit h-t-t-p //ppa_launchpad_net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign h-t-t-p //ppa_launchpad_net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit h-t-t-p //us_archive_ubuntu_com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit h-t-t-p //extras_ubuntu_com precise/main i386 Packages              
Ign h-t-t-p //extras_ubuntu_com precise/main TranslationIndex           
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/restricted Sources   
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/universe Sources
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit h-t-t-p //security_ubuntu_com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Ign h-t-t-p //extras_ubuntu_com precise/main Translation-en_US          
Ign h-t-t-p //ppa_launchpad_net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign h-t-t-p //extras_ubuntu_com precise/main Translation-en
Ign h-t-t-p //ppa_launchpad_net precise/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

root@ubuntu1204-cshr3:~# sudo apt-get remove initramfs-tools-bin && sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (>= 0.99ubuntu13.1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (< 0.99ubuntu13.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues including unmet dependencies and package configuration.

To solve the dependancy problem run:

```
sudo apt-get remove initramfs-tools-bin && sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools
```

To resolve the dpkg error run :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f
```

If not resolved :

```
sudo dpkg -r udev apparmor initramfs-tools && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install udev apparmor initramfs-tools
```

If still having the problem :

Run  `gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status` . In the Resulting text document, search for the sections start with `package : udev` , `package :apparmor`, `package :initramfs-tools`  and delete all the sections.

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install udev apparmor initramfs-tools
```

EDIT:

For the latest problem you encountered :Run:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists && sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial && sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: No joy! | root@ubuntu1204-cshr3:~# sudo apt-get install udev apparmor initramfs-tools
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: PS - I've done all three steps, in the order shown above. Each step fails with errors. Thx!

Comment: Have you done the last option ?. Run `sudo apt-get clean && sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists && sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: <snip> Get:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en [27.6 kB]
Fetched 19.7 MB in 58s (336 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
root@ubuntu1204-cshr3:~#